# Added liquidity on Uniswap but haven't got the LP token

Tags: uniswap, polygon, decentralized-exchange

This is the first time I have added Liquidity to uniswap in Matic/DAI pair at 0.3% reward. But when I have added the liquidity uniswap doesn't provide me the LP token which represents that I have added the liquidity.

Does anyone knows why uniswap haven't provided me LP token even for providing the liquidity?

Answer (score 0):

It depends if you used Uniswap v1 (LP token) or v2 (NFT token), in either case youll see the token in the wallet explorer on etherscan.

If its not showing in your wallet, youll need to add the LP token contract as a new coin

Comment: I have staked on uniswap v3. What is contract address of the LP token so that I can check.